# Unpivot table with multiple columns and dynamic column names

Tags: sql, dynamic, multiple-columns, unpivot, dynamic-columns

I am trying to unpivot a table with multiple rows and columns. Each row needs to be extratced to 2 rows with specific columns and the column names need to be renamed and a new column needs to added based on the columns selected!

I am including before and after sample data and a script to setup the data.

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmpProducts (
        ProductId INT,
        ProductName nVARCHAR(100),
        B2B_GrossRevenue DECIMAL(10,2),
        B2B_DirectCost DECIMAL(10,2),
        B2B_NetRevenue DECIMAL(10,2),
        B2C_GrossRevenue DECIMAL(10,2),
        B2C_DirectCost DECIMAL(10,2),
        B2C_NetRevenue DECIMAL(10,2)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts SELECT 1, 'Product1',1545.00,406.25,1138.75,195.00,35.10,159.90
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts SELECT 2, 'Product2',902.00,189.00,713.00,3280.00,590.40,2689.60
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts SELECT 3, 'Product3',15665.00,3988.39,11676.61,6247.00,1124.46,5122.54
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts SELECT 4, 'Product4',736.00,196.16,539.84,2395.00,431.10,1963.90

    SELECT * FROM #tmpProducts
    DROP TABLE #tmpProducts

    CREATE TABLE #tmpProducts2 (
        ProductId INT,
        ProductName nVARCHAR(100),
        [Type] nVARCHAR(3),
        GrossRevenue DECIMAL(10,2),
        DirectCost DECIMAL(10,2),
        NetRevenue DECIMAL(10,2)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts2 SELECT 1, 'Product1','B2B',1545.00,406.25,1138.75
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts2 SELECT 1, 'Product1','B2C',195.00,35.10,159.90
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts2 SELECT 2, 'Product2','B2B',902.00,189.00,713.00
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts2 SELECT 2, 'Product2','B2C',3280.00,590.40,2689.60
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts2 SELECT 3, 'Product3','B2B',15665.00,3988.39,11676.61
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts2 SELECT 3, 'Product3','B2C',6247.00,1124.46,5122.54
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts2 SELECT 4, 'Product4','B2B',736.00,196.16,539.84
    INSERT INTO #tmpProducts2 SELECT 4, 'Product4','B2C',2395.00,431.10,1963.90

    SELECT * FROM #tmpProducts2
    DROP TABLE #tmpProducts2
```

I have attempted this but i can't get past the second column and im not sure how at add a new column with specific text, (probably  dynamic sql but trying to avoid this if possible)

Here is the start of my attempt, any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT  ProductId, ProductName,GrossRevenue
        FROM    (
                    SELECT ProductId, ProductName, B2B_GrossRevenue,B2C_GrossRevenue FROM #tmpProducts
                ) as t
            UNPIVOT ( GrossRevenue for test IN (B2B_GrossRevenue,B2C_GrossRevenue)) AS unpvt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just keep unpivoting

```
    SELECT  ProductId,ProductName, Substring(col1,1,3) as type,  GrossRevenue, DirectCost, NetRevenue
    FROM    ( 
        SELECT * FROM #tmpProducts 
    ) as t 
    UNPIVOT ( GrossRevenue for col1 IN (B2B_GrossRevenue,B2C_GrossRevenue)) AS unpvt 
    unpivot ( DirectCost for col2 in (B2b_DirectCost, B2c_DirectCost)) up2
    unpivot ( NetRevenue for col3 in (B2b_NetRevenue, B2c_NetRevenue)) up3
where SUBSTRING(col1,1,3)=SUBSTRING(col2,1,3)
and  SUBSTRING(col1,1,3)=SUBSTRING(col3,1,3)
```

and join on the col columns to filter out mismatches

Comment: That did the job perfectly. Thank you for your help. First time accepting an answer on statckoverflow. Do i just click to accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this using Dynamic SQL.  This will allow you to get all of the columns upon execution. Then you will not have to alter the query if you get any data changes.  This does both an `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @colsUnPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @colsUnPivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('tmpProducts') and
               C.name like 'B2%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

SET @colsPivot = stuff((select DISTINCT ','+quotename(right((C.name), len(C.name)-4))
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('tmpProducts') and
               C.name like 'B2%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')


set @query 
  = ' SELECT ProductId, ProductName, [type], ' + @colsPivot +'
      FROM
      (
        SELECT ProductId, ProductName, substring(field, 1, 3) [type]
                ,  value, right((field), len(field)-4) as col
        from tmpProducts
        unpivot 
        (
           value
           for field in (' + @colsUnPivot + ')
        ) unpvt 
      ) x
      PIVOT
      (
        sum(value)
        FOR col IN (' + @colsPivot +')
      )p'


execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eef9f/26)

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Podiluska's answer did the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple groups that you're looking to pivot around you can also do something like this:

```
Select *
  from table
  unpivot include nulls ( (test_name, test_date) for col_nm in ( (test1, date1) as 'test_val1'
                                                                ,(test2, date2) as 'test_val2'
                                                                ,(test3, date3) as 'test_val3'
                                                               )
                     )
```